# Dataframe-js with filtering not works with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, dataframe-js

I'm trying to use filter in dataframe-js this way:

```
df?.filter(row => row.get('foo') >= 3)
```

This gives me the TS compiler warning `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'DataFrame | Record<string, any>'`.

Why is this happening if it's completely the same as in the documentation example?